# calling public method from another js function inside service

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created custom service

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")        
        .factory("redirectService",
                ["$q", "$location", 
                 redirectService])
        .config(function ($httpProvider) {
             $httpProvider.interceptors.push('redirectService');
        });

    function redirectService($q, $location){
       ...
       var redirect = function() {
            ...
        };

        return {           
            doRedirect: redirect
        };
     }
```

inside my other controller where I'm injecting this redirectService I'm trying to call this publish doRedirect method

```
angular
    .module("myModule")
    .controller("MyController",
                 ["$scope",  
                 "redirectService"                  
                  MyController]);

    function MyController(redirectService){
      vm.doClick = function() {  
        redirectService.doRedirect();
      }
    }
```

Here I'm getting error on calling doRedirect method

> Error: redirectService.doRedirect is not a function

Comment: Could it be that loginRedirectService should be redirectService on the call

Comment: you create redirect function but try to return redirectPostLogin. Or you just pasted the code wrongly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an imbalance of number of arguments in dependency array and function arguments for `MyController`

Change

```
function MyController(redirectService){
```

To

```
function MyController($scope, redirectService){
```

Answer (score 0):

MyController function has two arguments first $scope, second redirectService

```
angular
    .module("myModule")
    .controller("MyController",
                 ["$scope",  
                 "redirectService"                  
                  MyController]);

    function MyController($scope, redirectService){
      vm.doClick = function() {  
        redirectService.doRedirect();
      }
    }
```